# Annotating a Django QuerySet with the Sum of the Max of a Subquery

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I'm struggling to compile a Queryset with a mildly complicated annotation, on the basis of which I'd sort the Queryset.

When working with such problems, I favour spinning off a generalised minimalist test bed and for this one I have this set of models:

```py
from django.db import models

class Top(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Middle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    klass = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(Top, related_name='middles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Lower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(Middle, related_name='lowers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Top and Middle are unique and Lower is not, Lower objects of the same name exist under different Middles and Tops but with a unique and sequential rank.

The challenge I have is expressed in English (natural language) as follows:

Annotate Tops with the sum of the maximum ranks of all Lowers in a given klass (or all klasses).

I can extract these individually for a given top and klass, for example:

```py
 def test_top(top, klass=None):
     l_filter = Q(reports_to__reports_to=top)
     if not klass is None:
         l_filter &= Q(reports_to__klass=klass)
     highest_ranks = Lower.objects.filter(l_filter).values('reports_to__reports_to', 'name').annotate(highest_rank=Max('rank')).values('highest_rank')
     sum_highest_ranks = highest_ranks.aggregate(total=Sum('highest_rank'))
     print(f"\t\tGot sum of {sum_highest_ranks}, for {top.name} from:")
     for r in highest_ranks:
         print(f"\t\t\t{r}")
```

Have checked this empirically and it works well. But this involves evaluating a Queryset for each indivitual Top. I seek a Queryset of Tops, a la:

```
tops = Top.objects.all().annotate(sum_highest_ranks=...).order_by('-sum_highest_ranks')
```

And cannot find the missing ...

I have in fact come as far as:

```py
def test_query(klass=None, top=None):
     if top is None:
         l_filter = Q(reports_to__reports_to=OuterRef('id'))
     else:
         l_filter = Q(reports_to__reports_to=top)
     if not klass is None:
         l_filter &= Q(reports_to__klass=klass)

     hr = Lower.objects.filter(l_filter).values('reports_to__reports_to', 'name').annotate(highest_rank=Max('rank')).values('highest_rank')

     if top:
         print(f"\t\t{top.name} drill down to highest ranks:")
         for l in hr:
             print(f"\t\t\t{l}")
     else:
         Tops = Top.objects.annotate(high_rank_sums=Sum(Subquery(hr)))

         for t in Tops:
             print(f"\t\t{t.name}, {t.high_rank_sums}")
```

But this produces suprising and incorrect results. The SQL looks fine, it generates:

```sql
SELECT "DjangoAnnotation_top"."id",
       "DjangoAnnotation_top"."name",
       SUM(
             (SELECT MAX(U0."rank") AS "highest_rank"
              FROM "DjangoAnnotation_lower" U0
              INNER JOIN "DjangoAnnotation_middle" U1 ON (U0."reports_to_id" = U1."id")
              WHERE U1."reports_to_id" = ("DjangoAnnotation_top"."id")
              GROUP BY U1."reports_to_id", U0."name")) AS "high_rank_sums"
FROM "DjangoAnnotation_top"
GROUP BY "DjangoAnnotation_top"."id",
         "DjangoAnnotation_top"."name"
```

But the SUM on the MAX seems not to be the SUM of those MAX values at all. It seems not to returns the SUM, but the FIRST. For example I can evaluate the inner SELECT MAX in SQL

```sql
SELECT MAX(U0."rank") AS "highest_rank"
      FROM "DjangoAnnotation_lower" U0
      INNER JOIN "DjangoAnnotation_middle" U1 ON (U0."reports_to_id" = U1."id")
      WHERE U1."reports_to_id" = 4
      GROUP BY U1."reports_to_id", U0."name"
```

and I see:

```
3
5
5
5
4
5
3
4
4
8
6
4
5
1
```

and yet the full query produces:

```
1   Edward Cox  1
2   Rufus Brown 2
3   Ronald Roberts  3
4   Nancy Fernandez 3
5   Jill Tuley  4
```

Note Top 4 has a result of 3.

I have all this in a very small Django App here:

https://github.com/bernd-wechner/DjangoAnnotation

including a sample database (SQLite).

Any insights here would be deeply appreciated.

### Update

I have using the [DB browser for SQL Lite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) generated SQL that will do what I want:

```sql
SELECT topname, SUM(max)
FROM
    (SELECT T."name" AS topname, L."name" AS lowname, MAX(L."rank") AS max
     FROM "DjangoAnnotation_top" T
     INNER JOIN "DjangoAnnotation_middle" M ON M.reports_to_id = T.id
     INNER JOIN "DjangoAnnotation_lower" L ON L.reports_to_id = M.id
     GROUP BY T."id",T."name", L."name")
GROUP BY topname
```

This however relies on selecting from a subquery, not a strength that Django has I fear. The only solution I'm aware of is the ghastly reliance on raw SQL:

```py
def test_query(klass=None):
  where_klass = "" if klass is None else f'WHERE M."klass"={klass}\n'
  query = f"""
      SELECT id, name, SUM(max) AS high_rank_sums
      FROM
          (SELECT T."id" AS id, T."name" AS name, MAX(L."rank") AS max
           FROM "DjangoAnnotation_top" T
           INNER JOIN "DjangoAnnotation_middle" M ON M.reports_to_id = T.id
           INNER JOIN "DjangoAnnotation_lower" L ON L.reports_to_id = M.id
           {where_klass}GROUP BY T."id",T."name", L."name")
      GROUP BY id, name
  """

  Tops = Top.objects.raw(query)

  for t in Tops:
    print(f"{t.name}, {t.high_rank_sums}")
```

It remains a puzzle to me why the Django Queryset above and the SQL it generates, which looks right to my eye, fails to return the SUM of the MX, but returns the FIRST of the MAX. And I wonder if there's a way, short of Raw SQL to produce SQL like this sample or functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work

```py
class MaxSubquery(Subquery):
    template = '(SELECT MAX("%(max_field)s") FROM (%(subquery)s) subquery)'

    def __init__(self, max_field, queryset, output_field, **extra):
        super().__init__(queryset, output_field, max_field=max_field, **extra)

class SumSubquery(Subquery):
    template = '(SELECT SUM("%(sum_field)s") FROM (%(subquery)s) subquery)'

    def __init__(self, sum_field, queryset, output_field, **extra):
        super().__init__(queryset, output_field, sum_field=sum_field, **extra)




related_lower_qs = Lower.objects.all()
related_lower_qs = related_lower_qs.filter(reports_to__reports_to_id=OuterRef("pk"))

highest_rank_qs = related_lower_qs.values("rank")

highest_rank_sum_qs = related_lower_qs.filter(rank=OuterRef("highest_rank")) 
highest_rank_sum_qs =highest_rank_sum_qs.values("rank")

qs = Top.objects.all()
qs = qs.alias(highest_rank=MaxSubquery("rank", queryset=highest_rank_qs, output_field=models.IntegerField()))
qs = qs.annotate(highest_rank_sum=SumSubquery("rank", queryset=highest_rank_sum_qs, output_field=models.IntegerField()))
```

Comment: Sorry for the tardy reply and thanks very muchly for the interesting angle on this. Certainly a direction to explore. The precise solution you've shared fails to produce the expected results, but I can see the SQL, and will think about what's wrong and whether it can be fixed and get back. Alas, sharing SQL in comments is not easy here and SO in general not well set up for technical to and fro, but you've provided something to chew on which I appreciate and an insight into an undocumented feature of the Subquery implementation (derived classes with templates).

Comment: Found the break in this. The SQL generated includes a Where conditions on a match of ranks a la `U0."rank" = SELECT MAX("rank")` which is clearly not useful. `rank` is not a key by any measure, not a useful JONI criterion. Will play a bit and see if the actual pks can be used while retaining the gist of your approach.

Comment: And the cause is this `.filter(rank=OuterRef("highest_rank")) ` creating a conundrum. As we do need to draw up the highest_ranks but we need to JOIN on a match of ids not the rank. This avenue may be a dead end?

Comment: You could rewrite this so that the MaxSubquery is annotated on the highest_rank_sum_qs instead of getting it from the outer query. It will probably be heavier to compute but it might works. `related_lower_qs.filter(rank=MaxSubquery("rank",Lower.object.filter(reports_to__reports_to_id=OuterRef(OuterRef("pk"))).values("rank")))`  
As an other way to solve this, maybe you could get away with one subquery and clever grouping (with a max and a count) since your sum can be computed by max*count. However won't be able to try to write that for the following days

Comment: Any filter on 'rank=' suffers the same problem, rank is not a unique key so not an appropriate filter (multiple lowers can have the same rank and the same maximum rank). One possible approach is to build an annotation, being a string in format "id, rank" if it's possible to filter on id__startswith="id," and annotate with the rank extracted from "id,rank".